# How to rotate Fontisto icon in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I Import Fontisto `import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";`

Add an Icon `<Fontisto style={styles.windDirectionArrow} name='arrow-up' />`

and the styling to rotate it

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    windDirectionArrow: {
        fontSize: 40,
        transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
    },
});
```

But the transform is not working, does anyone know any other solutions for this?

The view I am rendering looks like this

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {error ? (
                <View style={styles.centeredContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Unable to load weather data</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{error}</Text>
                </View>
            ) : isLoading ? (
                <View style={styles.centeredContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Loading Weather Data</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        style={styles.activityIndicator}
                        size='large'
                        color='rgb(255,179,25)'
                    />
                </View>
            ) : (
                <View style={[styles.centeredContainer]}>
                    <Fontisto style={styles.text} name={icon} />
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{temperature}˚C</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        <Fontisto name='arrow-up' style={styles.windDirectionArrow} />
                        {windSpeed}mph
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{weatherCondition}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
```

It works if I have the Icon element wrapped in its own  but I think that is not a clean solution

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
    <View>
        <Fontisto name='arrow-up' style={styles.windDirectionArrow} />
    </View>
    {windSpeed}mph
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly for me

```
// With Rotation
<Fontisto name="arrow-up" style={styles.windDirectionArrow} />

// Without Rotation
<Fontisto name="arrow-up" style={styles.withoutRottion} />

// When icon is wrapped inside a View and that View is rotated
<View style={styles.windDirectionArrow}>
   <Fontisto name="arrow-up" style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
</View>
```

My Styles :

```
 windDirectionArrow: {
    fontSize: 40,
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }],
  },
  withoutRottion: {
    fontSize: 40,
  },
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/icon-rotate)

And also why don't you use `arrow-right` from `Fontisto`

And for Text Side by side

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <View style={styles.windDirectionArrow}>
    <Fontisto name="arrow-up" style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.text}>{windSpeed}mph</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, firstly I am using the up arrow so I can rotate the arrow based on the direction of the wind. Secondly I have now realised that the rotation only works when the Fontisto icon element is within its own <View> tag, I have updated the original question with code snippets to show you what I mean and give context to the code I am rendering.

Comment: So what you can do is Wrap the Icon inside the `View` tag and then rotate that View...I mean apply the rotation style to that View.

Comment: So I want some text next to the arrow (not rotated) but if I have the Icon in a rotated View tag it will instead be on a new line, is there a work around for this?